# Android Studio and google play services error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I want to add admob to my project and have followed the instructions from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) but I'm getting an error:

`Cannot find symbol '@integer/google_play_services_version`

inside the `AndroidManifest.xml`. I've looked inside the sdk directory and google_play_services version 4.0.30 is installed. Here's  my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
productFlavors {
    defaultFlavor {
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
}
```

After adding it, I've synced the project with gradle. I also have the required entry in `AndroidManifest.xml` which gives me the error

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

The official docs say that for android studio we don't need to include the library but I don't understand why it doesn't find it.

---

Edit: I finally solved it. **The problem was that I was using the wrong sdk. Android studio ships with its own SDK and that was set as default in the IDE.**

### To fix

- **Change your project's SDK from `android-studio\\sdk` to `android-sdk`. If you don't know how, [here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path).**
- If you get an error about build tools not found make sure the version in your `build.gradle` corresponds to your new sdk's version.

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081598/import-google-play-services-library-in-android-studio/21086904#21086904

Comment: @pyus13 From what you linked: "The com.google.android.gms.version number resolves fine in my manifest." - It doesn't in mine.

Comment: If you're still getting the error, could you please post the complete logcat? Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel make sure you have downloaded Google Repository from SDK Manager.

Comment: @Daniel regarding your edit, if your local.properties file have different SDK path than Project sdk , Android Studio is smart enough to tell you that there is some conflicts in sdk paths in your local.properties in a dialog and you can correct it by just clicking on a button in dialog so no need to bother about about local.properties file.

Comment: @pyus13 It didn't for me.

Comment: @Daniel it is introduced in AS 0.3.7 release which version of studio are you using ?

Comment: @pyus13 AS 0.4 Sorry about about, I edited my question in a hurry. What I meant to say was that `build.gradle` had the `buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'` and the new sdk had version `19.0.1`, so I got an error because of that. Thanks for noticing. And yes, you are correct, the `local.properties` file was modified by the IDE :)

Comment: Thanks a ton. @Daniel. You've saved my day. Mwaaaah :)

Answer (score 3):

You must have **Google Repository** installed in order to use **Google Play Services** in Android Studio.

If not Installed it from **SDK Manager > Extras**.

After Installation your library should be located on path

```
 $SDK_DIR\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services
```

Comment: I do have it installed.

Comment: @Daniel i have tried in my machine and everything seems fine. Can you please include your Gradle Console output( only error part) in question.