# Symbol not found, but Builds and Run OK on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I have a strange issue with Android Studio. It doesn't find the symbol references to the Google Play Services libs, as you can see in the picture:

[image]

My `build.gradle` file is looking like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32'
}
```

The strange thing, is that I can build and even Run the application in my phone with no problem.
This problem makes the IDE so useful as the notepad, when I want to use the `com.google.android.gms.*` library. How can I solve this issue?

I'm using version 0.4.2

Comment: There's an issue with 0.4.2 that's documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols/21100896#21100896 It should hopefully be fixed in 0.4.3, which is available in the canary update channel. You can try upgrading, or if you don't want to upgrade, follow the instructions in the answer to that question. If you have problems with 0.4.3, definitely let us know -- there may be some lingering problems we need to address.

Comment: Alright @ScottBarta, I will try updating

Comment: Yeap @ScottBarta, now is working fine :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look in to this

[Import Google Play Services library in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081598/import-google-play-services-library-in-android-studio/21086904#21086904)

Another workaround is :

[Android Studio suddenly cannot resolve symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols/21100896#21100896)

It was an issue in Android Studio 0.4.2 which is resolved in latest release 0.4.3, I recommend you to update your Android Studio.

Comment: I've tried updating to 0.4.3 and it's working fine now. Thanks

Comment: It's better to mark these questions as duplicates instead of having copy/paste answers all over Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ScottBarta thanks for suggestion, actually I need to include the lines for update so I did not refer the old one, otherwise people will be used to of workaround instead having a solution.

Comment: @ScottBarta I have updated my answer, Thanks alot for improvement.