# Android Studio project unable to find com.google.android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have two Android Studio projects using Google Maps.  One works fine, the other is unable to find com.google.android and so can't compile.  Fails with

```
error: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not exist
```

Both have the same code in Manifest.xml

`<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4323000" />`

Both have the same import statement.

build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

I've read several similar questions on StackOverflow but those answers have no beneficial effect.

Any thoughts appreciated ...

Comment: Make sure that you use the Google API

Comment: Please post your build.gradle

Comment: Did you add Google Play services ????

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081598/import-google-play-services-library-in-android-studio) too..

Comment: @Lal thanks for the suggestion.  Google Play Services Rev 16 was added via SDK Manager, but it seems you have to manually add it via Project/Structure as a Dependency also.  (I didn't do that on the project that was working already, but it does show up there, so somehow it added automatically in that case)  Anyway, after manual addition it now works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Andrew.. Happy that you got it right..:) I have added that as my answer..Can you please mark my answer as accepted..If you can please upvote my answer too..

Comment: @Lal I've upticked your comments above, but don't see your answer or acceptance of the question yet

Comment: Hi @Andrew.. I've added it as my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Please add Google Play services to your project..

Google Play Services Rev 16 was added via SDK Manager, but it seems you have to manually add it via Project/Structure as a Dependency also. (You didn't do that on the project that was working already, but it does show up there, so somehow it added automatically in that case) So kindly add that manually..

Answer (score 0):

Add this to **dependencies**:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
```

And replace (or leave) `4.3.23` with version you need, i.e. `4.3.+`