# My Admob ad id doesn't work. yet other id worked fine

Tags: android-studio, firebase, admob, ads, banner-ads

I made an app that contains an Admob ads . I did everything as in the tutorial and everything was working fine until i put my own Ad id  it didn't show . But when I change the Ad id to any ad id from the internet or from tutorials it works fine . I dunno where is the problem exactly .. is it from the codes or from my admob.

here is the codes :

```
    public class main extends Activity {
WebView web1;
private AdView mAdView;
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //full screen ads
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4400857573550757/5605673426");
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
        }
    });
    requestNewInterstitial();
    //---------------- START ORDERING BANNER ADD ------------
    // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
   MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-4400857573550757/2713039825");
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

   // System.out.println(adRequest.isTestDevice(this))
    //---------------------------------------------------
   // mInterstitialAd.show();
    this.setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                        } else {
                           // beginPlayingGame();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 60000); //execute in every 10 ms

    web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = web1.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    web1.loadUrl("MYWEBSITE");

    web1.setWebViewClient(new NoErrorWebViewClient());

}

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
           // .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")


    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}}
```

and here is the layout codes :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingBottom="1dp"
android:paddingLeft="1dp"
android:paddingRight="1dp"
android:paddingTop="1dp"
tools:context=".main">


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />




<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4400857573550757/2713039825" /></RelativeLayout>
```

I uploaded the log here : [log](http://dent11.com/errorlogandroid.txt)

Comment: please share logs ( filter for Ads )

Comment: @AmodGokhale I added the log . thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

```
09-03 08:14:53.186 2726-2726/muteb.speak I/Ads: Starting ad request.
09-03 08:14:53.190 2726-2726/muteb.speak I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("19AA808AE9FC61F7FA6E4AA2B99F2557") to get test ads on this device.
09-03 08:14:53.258 2726-2726/muteb.speak W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
09-03 08:14:53.262 2726-2726/muteb.speak W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
09-03 08:14:53.270 2726-2726/muteb.speak I/Ads: Starting ad request.
09-03 08:14:53.274 2726-2726/muteb.speak I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("19AA808AE9FC61F7FA6E4AA2B99F2557") to get test ads on this device.
```

See above logs... Device you are testing needs to be updated with Google Play Services library refer to this link [Android Studio with Google Play: Google Play services is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703145/android-studio-with-google-play-google-play-services-is-missing)

Comment: I have tried putting a generated .Apk of my app on my updated Note4 still not working with me . Notice that other Ads Id works fine .

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if JavaScript is enabled 
      `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
the banner from AdMob will not work (at least in my case).

I couldn't find a workaround for this situation, but I am very much looking forward to hear others ideas.