# add google play library to project android studio

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android project which developed in eclipse which using google play services
Now I have migrated that project in android studio.
When i run this project it shows an error

```
Error:(49, 35) java: package com.google.android.gms.maps does not exist
```

In sdk Google Play services was missing
then i installed
Google Play services
Google Repository

But same error occurring

I referred some questions on stackoverflow like
 [Import Google Play Services library in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081598/import-google-play-services-library-in-android-studio)

they are saying you dont need to import any library project
just configure your build.gradle file

But as the project imported from eclipse to android studio
i cant see build.gradle file here

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project > open module setting > select App > dependencies > click on plus button > add library dependencies > googleplayservices

OR 
Add this in your gradle file 
dependencies {...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'...}
then build again

Comment: I tried with your first option :                                                               project > open module setting > select App > dependencies > click on plus button > add library dependencies >  but google play services library is not listed in my projects libs folder

Comment: but still error is present.OK could you tell me where gradle file located if you migrated from eclipse to android studio

Comment: How did you import your project to android studio did you make it gradle compatible

Comment: In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the Welcome to Android Studio window.
Click Import Non-Android Studio project. Then locate your project and click ok.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html. I referred this documentation. but i have only source code from eclipse. my project is not exported from eclipse.Is I have to export project from eclipse to generate gradle files